# Statistical tests for compositional data

Tags: statistical-significance, compositional-data

I have two vectors, $W_1 \in R^n$ and $W_2 \in R^n$, both lie on an $n-1$ simplex. So, $W_1$ and $W_2$ are compositions. I would like to verify if the difference between these two compositions are statistically significant. Apparently, the use of tests like paired t-test or Wilcoxon Signed-rank test should be avoided since they do not deal with compositional data.

Is there any modification of the tests which are especially tailored for the compositional data?! Or, is there any other way for the comparison?

Comment: I assume you have multiple observations from both sources? If you have only one vector each, you can't say anything about statistical significance (it would be the analogue for testing whether two single observations are statistically significantly different). [Is there a multivariate two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/273478/1352) may be helpful.

Comment: In fact I only have two vectors whose elements show the importance of an attribute. By using the statistical tests, I would to check the difference between the importance of attributes in the two given vectors.

Comment: Ah. So do I understand correctly, the fact that your data sum to 1 are an artifact of a normalization? And do you have just two measurements for each attribute, one in each vector?

Comment: I indeed have two measurement for each attribute, and the whole vector (e.g, W_1) is the outcome of some methods that solve an optimization problem with unit-sum constraint.
Does it make any difference if they are an artifact of a normalization?

Comment: Well, it depends on whether the normalization makes inherent sense. It may be better to just work on the un-normalized data. But even then, if you have only a single observation per attribute and vector, you can't figure out whether the vectors differ *on specific attributes*, because you have no notion of the variability.

Comment: Can't we account the difference between the importance of attributes as a source of variability? I do not want to see it as a multivariate variable and not seeking a multivariate statistics.

I thought of one workaround: if we divide all the elements in W_1 and W_2 to, say, the last element, we will have two n-1 dimensional vectors (say Y_1 and Y_2) that shows the ratio of each element to the last element. Now, can apply the statistical tests to these log(Y_1) and log(Y_2), since log(Y_1) and log(Y_2) lie in the real space?! (Y_1 and Y_2 are additive log-ratio transformation of W_1 and W_2)